# Need to get value from a lookup table

Tags: sql

I have a table-X with ecode,emp ID ( some values)

```
37,10
47,20
57,30
```

There are 2 lookup tables

lookup table 1 has just the emp ID details( which am interested in)

```
10
20
```

so when i join..i get all the values needed (thats one part)

my result will be

```
37 10
47 20
```

second part is,

the ones which doesnt satisfy the join condition should lookup on table 2 which has
2 columns

```
ecode, other_codes
37  xxx
47  YYY
57  AAA
```

So when 30 comes in , i want to return AAA  and my final dataset should be,

```
37, 10
47,20
57 AAA
```

appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the SQL (to create the data and what you've tried so far) or a working example e.g. [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: just left join the first time with first table and do it the second time with second table on ecode is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join both tables and use CASE statement for selecting a value from one table or the other.

I've created a db-fiddle which I think exemplifies your situation based on your description: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ujW8Unf44CqbsiJZXqXXtK/0

Here is the code for posterity. To set up your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tableX (       
   eCode int,       
   employeeId int 
); 
INSERT INTO tableX (eCode, employeeId) VALUES (37, 10); 
INSERT INTO tableX (eCode, employeeId) VALUES (47, 20); 
INSERT INTO tableX (eCode, employeeId) VALUES (57, 30);

CREATE TABLE employeeIds (employeeId int); 
INSERT INTO employeeIds (employeeId) VALUES (10); 
INSERT INTO employeeIds (employeeId) VALUES (20);

CREATE TABLE otherCodes (       
   eCode int,       
   other_codes varchar(10) 
); 
INSERT INTO otherCodes (eCode, other_codes) VALUES (37, 'XXX'); 
INSERT INTO otherCodes (eCode, other_codes) VALUES (47, 'YYY'); 
INSERT INTO otherCodes (eCode, other_codes) VALUES (57, 'AAA');
```

The query based on this schema:

```
SELECT 
    tx.eCode, 
    CASE WHEN ei.employeeId IS NULL THEN oc.other_codes ELSE ei.employeeId END as 'result'
FROM tableX tx
LEFT JOIN employeeIds ei ON tx.employeeId = ei.employeeId
LEFT JOIN otherCodes oc ON tx.eCode = oc.eCode;
```